# Ensure ROI crop coordinates (x,y,w,h) are valid and within bounds Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Given the `(x,y,w,h)` coordinates to crop a ROI from an image, how can I ensure that the given coordinates are valid? For example:

```
image = cv2.imread('1.jpeg')
x,y,w,h = 0,0,300,300
ROI = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
cv2.imshow('ROI', ROI)
cv2.waitKey()
```

If the `(x,y,w,h)` coordinates are invalid, it will throw this error:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:350: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

I'm trying to write a function to validate the coordinates before cropping the ROI. Currently, some of my checks are to ensure that:

1. `(x,y,w,h)` are all either `int` or `float` type
2. `x` and `y` are >= 0
3. `w` and `h` are > 0

Sometimes it still throws the error, what checks am I missing?

Example image:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2

def validate_ROI_coordinates(coordinates):
    # (x,y) is top left coordinates
    # Top right corner is is (x + w)
    # Bottom left corner is (y + h) 
    
    x,y,w,h = coordinates
    
    # Ensure its a number, not boolean or string type
    def int_or_float(s):
        try:
            i = int(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            try:
                f = float(s)
                return True
            except:
                return False
    
    def within_bounds(x,y,w,h):
        # Ensure that x and y are >= 0
        if x >= 0 and y >= 0:
            # Ensure w and h are > 0 ( can be any positive number)
            if w > 0 and h > 0:
                return True
        else:
            return False
    
    if all(int_or_float(value) for value in coordinates) and within_bounds(x,y,w,h):
        return True
    else:
        return False

image = cv2.imread('1.jpeg')
print(image.shape)
x,y,w,h = 500,0,6600,300
coordinates = (x,y,w,h)

if validate_ROI_coordinates(coordinates):
    ROI = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('ROI', ROI)
    cv2.waitKey()
else:
    print('Invalid ROI coordinates')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the coordinates are within the image range using the image resolution:

```py
# get resolution and coordinates
height, width = image.shape[:-1]
xmin, ymin, w, h = coordinates
xmax = xmin + w
ymax = ymin + h

# fetch roi
if (xmin  >= 0) and (ymin >= 0) and (xmax < width) and (ymax < height):
  roi = image[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
```